# Intelij - Structural Search and Replace in xhtml files

Tags: intellij-idea

I must update Primefaces version in my project, and I must change elements like

```
#{p:component('string')}
```

to

```
#{p:resolveFirstComponentWithId('string', view).clientId}
```

I tried something like that in Structural Search and Replace, where value text = \w*, but i got The specified template is malformed.
What's wrong here with my expression, what should I do?

[image]